# Magento CSS does not merge

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have `styles.css` and `styles2.css` when i merge CSS it does not add `styles2.css` in merged file.

Answer (score 0):

1) Firstly, have you declared your `style2.css` correctly?

2) See you the `style2.css` in the source code of the page with the right path if you disable the `merge option`?

3) Did you enabled the Merge option `Merge CSS Files` in admin as the image below

[image]

4) Clear Magento and Navigator cache.

Comment: yes when i unmerge css it shows style2.css but not when i merge